# Do I need to change my tactics playing pocket rockets (AA) to maximize their potential?

Tags: betting-strategy

When playing AA to maximize the potential return, I tend to bet a lot pre flop but that often leads to just stealing the blinds. Given this fact, should I limp and reraise if I can, given that I've been confronted with a "tight" field?

Comment: I think this question is too general to have an answer. How you should play any hand is going to depend on a lot more factors than just what the cards are.

Comment: I agree with @JeffreyBlake

Comment: I have edited this question and nominate it for re-opening in its current form.

Comment: @TomAu It's still way too broad! Really, almost any question that has a "How do I play X?" format, without additional info about table dynamics is likely too difficult to answer objectively. I'm going to leave it closed. I have no problem with the attempt to edit it though, that's a good thing :)

Comment: @TobyBooth: The "thrust" (or intent) of my edit was to narrow the question to, "now that I've been confronted with a "tight" field, should I "slowplay" by limping and re-raising?" Maybe I should have made that more explicit in my edit. I also constructed an answer to the "narrow" question in the comment below, which I would like to be able to convert to a "full" answer.

Comment: Yes, it seems that your opponents are "tight," and in your shoes, I would "limp" with aces. More to the point, I would raise with 2-2, and try to "steal" hands against such opponents, until I'm "caught." Then they'll start calling AA.

Comment: I've reconsidered the reasons for closing this, & they still hold IMO. The info is just too generic, will incite debate when people try to fill in the gaps to come to a meaningful answer. It's just "non-constructive" like the close reason suggests. I get what you're attempting, but it's a long way from where it should be. This question is the kind of thing people try and avoid on poker sites! I'll approve the edit but for now, it's still closed.

Answer (score 5):

There are so many things to consider when coming to a conclusion about how to play not just AA, but any hand.  Not the least of which is:

- Game Type & Format
- Stack Sizes
- Opponent Skill
- Hero's Image
- Opponent Tendancies
- Metagame (ie, history)
- Board Texture
- Opponent's Likely Range

The list goes on and on.

However, as a general rule of thumb (to which there are many exceptions), in a No-Limit Holdem Cash Game against amatuer opponents with whom you have no significant history, I posit that:

### The best way to make money with a good hand is to bet, bet, bet.

Comment: That's true if your opponents have no history. I take the question to mean that the OP's opponents have a "tight" history, which speaks to opponents' tendencies and opponent's likely range as well. Then would you start trying to steal hands with e.g. 2-2? And this is "pre flop," so there is no "board texture."

Answer (score 3):

From my experience, playing `AA` **slowplay is long term not effective** in compare to play that cards aggressive.

Comment: Please see my comment (above) to John Dibling.

Answer (score 2):

One general tips is to never limp! you want to raise the same amount with your whole range of hands to be as unpredictable as possible.
If you limp your AA, you will just end up in weird spots all the time where you have no idea what to do and what hands your opponents have (the BB or SB getting a cheap or free flop). This will result in closing your eyes and calling it down drawing thin or dead.

Aggression is the way to go! Even if it only results in stealing the blinds! taking the blinds are better than losing your stack! ;)

Comment: Never say never...it's rare that there is a good reason to limp AA, but it is possible.

Comment: Ok, I have a good scenario actually. When you are on the money bubble in a tournament and people on your table are shoving really light, you can limp your AA in early position and hope for a shove :) Other than that I never limp.